# Updating to Windows Fall Creator's Update creates endless BSOD on boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bsod

I'm trying to update my Windows 10 machine to Fall Creators. It does a few installs and reboots, but then eventually goes Blue Screen of Death with no specific files being noted beyond SYSTEM_THREAD_ETC_ETC...

It doesn't give me any chance to do anything. I see an "HP" logo, then a second or two later is the BSOD. No opportunity to see any desktop or anything.

I've been using Win+X on boot to reset my version.

How can I diagnose this update or fix what's happening? It's weird that it's such a major fatal error with no information.

Comment: You will have to use Windbg and analyze the mini dump file.  Without more information we cannot really help.  Additionally, if you mount the iso, and upgrade using that does anything change?

Answer (score 0):

If you had complete the system upgrading/installation, using Windows 10 installation medium, re-boot system from the installation medium, you can choose repair this computer, then, select Safe Mode to re-start system, or, open CMD and use “sfc /scannow” to check/repair system files.

If you had already re-set your system, before system upgrade, please check/install available update/hotfix via Windows Update, also, please check/update hardware drivers, make sure that all drivers are up to data and have the appropriate version which are applied to Windows 10 installed. using “sfc /scannow” to check/repair system files and using “chkdsk /r /f” to check/repay disks. In general, system health is helpful for avoiding some possible problem of system upgrade/update.

Comment: DISM is more efficient then SFC at repairing Windows installation  on Windows 8.1+ it’s doubtful the author has system corruption though

Comment: Unfortunately none of these things were able to help. I did some more research and found a few threads saying to basically skip the update and that it can't really be fixed.